# Is it possible to use Ropemacs with TRAMP in Emacs?

Tags: python, emacs, tramp, ropemacs

I recently installed the hg tip version of Ropemacs and I'd like to use it when editing remote files using TRAMP. Has anyone done this? When I try to use `M-/` to complete a variable name, I am asked to enter the `Rope project root folder` and I enter: `/ssh:myhost:/path/to/myproject/` and it gives me the following error:

```
Opening [/ssh:myhost:/path/to/myproject/] project ... 
pymacs-report-error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/saltycrane/lib/python-environments/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Pymacs/pymacs.py", line 147, in loop
    value = eval(text)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/saltycrane/lib/python-environments/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ropemode/decorators.py", line 53, in newfunc
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/saltycrane/lib/python-environments/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ropemode/interface.py", line 254, in code_assist
    _CodeAssist(self, self.env).code_assist(prefix)
  File "/home/saltycrane/lib/python-environments/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ropemode/interface.py", line 538, in code_assist
    proposals = self._calculate_proposals()
  File "/home/saltycrane/lib/python-environments/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ropemode/interface.py", line 597, in _calculate_proposals
    self.interface._check_project()
  File "/home/saltycrane/lib/python-environments/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ropemode/interface.py", line 448, in _check_project
    self.open_project()
  File "/home/saltycrane/lib/python-environments/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ropemode/decorators.py", line 53, in newfunc
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/saltycrane/lib/python-environments/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ropemode/interface.py", line 88, in open_project
    self.project = rope.base.project.Project(root)
  File "/home/saltycrane/lib/python-environments/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rope/base/project.py", line 134, in __init__
    os.mkdir(self._address)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/ssh:myhost:/path/to/myproject'
```

I imagine ropemacs doesn't support remote files with TRAMP. Just wondering if anyone has found a workaround. Maybe some custom elisp? Or maybe I should use sshfs and mount the remote filesystem locally...

I installed ropemacs in a virtualenv located at `/home/saltycrane/lib/python-environments/default`. I am using GNU Emacs 23.1.50.1 on Ubuntu Lucid.

I should mention that completion with `M-/` works fine when I'm not using TRAMP.

Comment: Using sshfs is probably the pragmatic approach. Waiting till ropemacs gets support for working over TRAMP, or patching ropemacs yourself, is definitely more effort.

Comment: +1 for sshfs, which follows the modularity principle of the Unix philosophy and does not only work with Emacs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible using TRAMP, because the Python `rope` library does **not** make calls back into Emacs when it wants to scan the filesystem for Python files to find their classes and functions — instead, it uses calls like `listdir()` and `open()` on the filesystem directly, without giving Emacs a chance to get in the way and intercept the special TRAMP-prefixed paths that you are editing.

Using `sshfs` might be possible, as the comments have mentioned, but for `rope` I imagine that it would be a *very* slow solution, since `rope` has to open so many files to find out the state of your project.

I generally leave `rope` off, or else figure out how to export an Emacs session from the remote system, when editing across a remote-filesystem link. I wonder if you could use something like `rsync` or `dropbox` or even a DVCS so that the files would be present on your local hard drive as immediately-accessible copies, but so that changes you save would get copied across?